# Get a browser cookie, and pass it to the server side rendering on nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I develop a project with nuxt js. And I get problem like this below.

- I get result from restful api of backend with asynchronous ajax
  request.
- I need add the result as a header to every quest with the
  ajax library of axios.
- So I save the result on browser cookie.
- When I need the result, I get it from cookie, and attach it on axios
  request.

Now, the problem is on the server side rendering, I can not get the browser cookie.

What am I gonna do with the problem?

Comment: May be this is happening because, your page is not refreshing.

Answer (score 5):

You can store the needed info in both local storage & cookie, e.g.

```
import Cookie from 'js-cookie'
....
setCookie(state, value) {
  if (process.client) {
    localStorage.setItem('cookie', value);
  }
  Cookie.set('cookie', value)
}
```

To read it (cookies are included in the request automatically)

```
getCookie(context, req) {
  // if server
  if (req) {
    if (req.headers.cookie) {
      const cookie = req.headers.cookie.split(';').find(...)
    }
  }
  // if client
  if (process.client) {
    const cookie = localStorage.getItem('cookie');
  }
}
```

And to remove

```
removeCookie(state) {
  if (process.client) {
    localStorage.removeItem('cookie');
  }
  Cookie.remove('cookie');
}
```

Comment: is this plugin file? or where placed?

Comment: I have those inside vuex store

Answer (score 3):

In Nuxt 3 and Nuxt 2 Bridge you can use [`useCookie`](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-cookie/)

> Nuxt provides an SSR-friendly composable to read and write cookies.

```js
const session = useCookie('session')
session.value = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can get the `req` (request) and `res` (response) from the nuxt `context`.

You can set a cookie via

```js
// client side
document.cookie = 'sessionId=some-id;';
document.cookie = 'userId=awesome-id;';

// or server side
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ['sessionId=some-id;', 'userId=awesome-id;']);
```